# How to open the TouchID page in settings page?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I'm a newbie on Objective-C. I want to open the TouchID page in the iPhone settings page but my code just opens the settings page in the online public source. I wrote the code below.

======open iPhone setting page=======

```
if (&UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString != NULL)
    {
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
        NSLog(@"&UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString != NULL");
    }
    else
    {
        // Present some dialog telling the user to open the settings app.
        NSLog(@"&UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString == NULL");
    }
```

How can I modify the code to fix this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**EDIT:**

**This solution no longer works on iOS 11+**

---

You can't do this prior to iOS 10.

That being said, you have to "find out" what is the url.

You can try this code:

```
// URL to open general settings in case the TouchID one was not found.
NSString * defaultSettingsStr = ( &UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString != NULL ? UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString : @"prefs:root" );

// Array of possible URLs, differ in various iOS versions
NSArray * urlStrs = @[@"App-Prefs:root=TOUCHID_PASSCODE",
                 @"Prefs:root=TOUCHID_PASSCODE",
                 defaultSettingsStr];

for (NSString * urlStr in urlStrs) {
   NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStr];

   if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:url]) {
       // openURL is deprecated since iOS 10
       [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
       break;
   }
}
```

Comment: "App-Prefs:root=TOUCHID_PASSCODE" doesn't work on iOS 11. Do you know any other solution?

Comment: To my understanding, it is no longer possible on iOS 11 to go anywhere but the main "settings" page. (so no going to any of the subsections anymore)

Comment: This solution will cause your app to be rejected by the review process - `App-Prefs:root` is considered a private API.